# Best way to remove a specific item in AsyncStorage

Tags: arrays, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm storing an array of objects in AsyncStorage and would like to know the best way to remove a specific object. Right now I´m passing an id to my function and then I loop through the array to match the id and remove the object and then the array in AsyncStorage is updated. This seems to work ok, but I wonder if this is optimal or if there is a better way to do this?

**My function right now:**

```
  export function removeData(id) {

    AsyncStorage.getItem('@books')
    .then((books) => {
    const updatedBooks = (JSON.parse(books))

        for (let i = 0; i < updatedBooks.length; i++) {
           if(updatedBooks[i].id == id) {
              updatedBooks.splice(i, 1);
          }
      }
      AsyncStorage.setItem('@books', JSON.stringify(updatedBooks));

   })
}
```

**My function for adding data to AsyncStorage:**

```
    export function addData(book) {

    AsyncStorage.getItem('@books')
    .then((books) => {
    const b = books ? JSON.parse(books) : [];
    b.push(book);
    AsyncStorage.setItem('@books', JSON.stringify(b));
  });  
}
```

**Button to add data with sample data to show structure:**

```
  <Button 
        title = "Add book"
        onPress={() => addData({
            id: 1,
            title: 'Harry Potter',
            author:'J.K. Rowling',
            thumbnail:'https://covers.openlibrary.org/w/id/7984916-M.jpg',
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

Later answer

> No, the thing that you are expecting cannot be achieved as
> AsyncStorage only store data in key value pairs. So the APIs exposed
> by AsyncStorage work only for string data, you need to parse the JSON
> do your logic and stringify and set to the AsyncStorage
> again.

To remove single item

```
AsyncStorage.removeItem('key', (err) => {
  // key 'key' will be removed, if they existed
  // callback to do some action after removal of item
});
```

To remove multiple items

```
let keys = ['k1', 'k2'];
AsyncStorage.multiRemove(keys, (err) => {
  // keys k1 & k2 removed, if they existed
  // callback to do some action after removal of item
});
```

Reference:

[RemoveItem method](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html#removeitem)
[MultiRemove method](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html#multiremove)

Comment: I'm using a single key to store my array of objects, and this approach would remove everything at that key. I want to remove specific items in the array stored at the key. My function works, I was just wondering if it is possible to do it in a better and more efficient way.

Comment: Please put the JSON data. I want to see the structure

Comment: Updated the post with the code for adding to AsyncStorage and the structure of the objects.